# Web service authentication - Token basis

Tags: web-services, database-design, authentication, data-modeling, kerberos

i am designing a database for web service authentication system, based on the KERBEROS working (using tokens instead of tickets). anybody help me to understand the data modeling for kerberos system. or where can i get some resources about the data schema for kerberos like authentication methods.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use Kerberos as-is. Period.

Comment: sorry michael, i need the design concept of kerberos only, not the kerberos system.

Comment: let me know, what RFC is, as i am a beginner
- thanks  in advance

Comment: Start wird [RFC2743](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2743.txt) and [RFC4120](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4120).